# Creating and Editing of Object with Multiple Dynamic Collections - DRY Principle

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, user-interface

I have the following class...

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<SizeOption> SizeOptions { get; set; }
    public IList<ColorOption> ColorOptions { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> SimilarProduct  { get; set; }
}
```

I won't elaborate on the details of each of those additional classes. What is important is that a `Product` contains multiple properties that are child collections.

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC3 (Razor) web application to help manage these products.

The UI must function in such a way that I have one area for editing the low level product details (Id, Name, Price, etc.) followed by separate areas below for each child collection on Product. (the client wants to manage everything about a product in one screen).

Those areas each have an "Add" button, which creates a new dynamic row with textboxes and various select/checkbox elements so the user can specify options for that object.  The user can add/remove these rows of child objects as much as they need to...this is all happening client side with the help of jQuery.  Nothing is saved until they submit the form.

**What I'm having trouble with is how best to design the layers involved.**

Currently, I have a partial view for the Edit Form which is used by the `Add Product` and `Edit Product` views.  This partial view leverages JavaScript functions to create the dynamic rows.  The markup for those dynamic rows is created in these functions in this fashion:

```
var newRow = $('<tr>').append(...) // etc.
table.append(newRow);
```

The problem with this approach, is that when I load the `Edit Product` view, I'm writing the existing child rows using MVC by iterating over the Model's child collections and outputting HTML markup for the rows.  For example...

```
@foreach(var sizeOption in Model.SizeOptions)
{
     <tr>... etc.</tr>
}
```

This means that I'm duplicating the UI for the rows...I don't like this.  I've tried serializing the Model to Json, and calling the client functions based on the data in the Json object, to keep the UI code in one place, but this produces visible latency, which I also do not like.

Lastly, to keep MVC Happy, when the form is finally posted, I iterate the HTML tables and update the Name attributes of the form elements to be in the form of `Product.SizeOptions[0].PropertyName` so that the MVC View Engine will give a fully hydrated View Model as an argument for my Action methods.

Ultimately I'm looking for advice on how to handle this type of dynamic adding/editing in a scalable and maintainable fashion.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) interesting. In it Steven Sanderson illustrates a nice technique that allows to dynamically edit a variable length lists in ASP.NET MVC. It uses a custom helper which allows for generating proper names of the input fields so that the default model binder is able to successfully retrieve the values when the form is submitted. As far as adding a row is concerned, he uses AJAX to invoke a controller action which renders a partial view which simply gets added to the DOM.